# Differences in compiling between gcc 4.4 and gcc 4.6?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I just moved from RH (CentOS 6) with gcc 4.4.6 to Ubuntu 12 with gcc 4.6.3.  I have a program that references a third party library.  I have successfully build and installed the library on the Ubuntu machine.  When I run `updatedb` and `locate libXXX.so` I get the same exact results.  I look for the header file the same way and also get the same exact results.

I have a small test program that came from the CentOS box.  It consists of one `*.c` file and a bash script to build and run it.  It's all very simple.  The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f a.out
gcc -W -lpowerdna *.c

exit 0
```

I have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set (on both the CentOS and Ubuntu boxes) to the directory where the header file and `*.so` reside.  I have double, triple, and quadruple checked that the spelling and the capitalization are correct.

And yet when I compile on the Ubuntu machine, I get the `undefined reference to '<function name>'` error for every function call in the test program.  To add to the general oddness, their defined types are not generating errors.  When I comment out the `#include` in my test file, the compiler generates errors for the types.

This is a very simple setup, with very few points of possible failure.  I'm certain I'm doing something stupid, but for the life of me, I don't see it.  For completeness, I'll post the pertinent parts.

Source file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include "PDNA.h"

// bare bones test program
```

Locate results:

```
[brian@localhost dmap403]$ locate PDNA.h  
/usr2/uei/DAQLib/PDNA.h

[brian@localhost dmap403]$ locate libpowerdna  
/usr2/uei/DAQLib/libpowerdna.so  
/usr2/uei/DAQLib/libpowerdna.so.4  
/usr2/uei/DAQLib/libpowerdna.so.4.4.0
```

Environment variable:

```
[brian@localhost dmap403]$ env | grep LD_
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr2/uei/DAQLib
```

When I compile on Ubuntu, I get these results:

```
/tmp/ccJAa183.o: In function 'main':  
dmap403.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to 'function name'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks like the compiler doesn't know where the `*.so` is, but I have it in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Heck, I even added `-L/usr2/uei/DAQLib -lpowerdna` to the gcc options to no avail.

**EDIT**:  Perhaps this should be moved to the Linux site?
**EDIT**:  Updated title to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...  I moved the `*.c` before the libraries and it compiled fine.  I didn't know that the order mattered.  Go figure...

Original:
`gcc -W -I/usr2/uei/DAQLib -L/usr2/uei/DAQLib  -lpowerdna *.c`

Current:
`gcc -W *.c -I/usr2/uei/DAQLib -L/usr2/uei/DAQLib  -lpowerdna`

C'est la vie.